# iOS - Check Previous Bundle Version

Tags: iphone, ios, nsbundle

Is it possible to programmatically check the bundle version of the previous app version installed? I know how to get the current version

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

The reason I ask is because there is a bug when updating my app from version A to C, but not B to C. I'd like to be able to check if the previous version was version A and if so, handle the bug accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

save the version in NSUserDefault

everytime  app shutdown or after the checking of the version

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:version  forKey:@"version"];
```

check it  at the beginning of the app runs

```
NSString *newVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

NSString *oldVersion =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"];
```

compare newVersion & oldVersion

Comment: My problem is that version A has already been released in the App Store. I cannot change that binary anymore. So version A is never being saved to the defaults. You follow me?

Comment: so as far as i know, you can't know the previous version if you didn't log it :(